# generate angular componenet based generic paramter

Tags: angular, generics

for a dialog component , that contain generic parameter of child component.
is there any way to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` based on generic Parameter (for example: `T`),

for this code :

```
export class CustomModal<T extends Component > implements OnInit {
......
@ViewChild('container')
  public container: ViewContainerRef;
  loadComponent(): void {
    let child= this.container.createComponent(T);
    //Error:  'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
  }
```

I have go this error:

```
'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Type<any>` instead of `T`.
Alternatively, you can create a common parent class (ex: `AppDynamicComponent`) for all your dynamic child components to extend, and then use `Type<AppDynamicComponent>`.

The `createComponent` APIs take `Type<C>` as input for the `component` parameter, according to the docs:

- https://angular.io/api/core/createComponent
- https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent

`Type<>` can be imported `from '@angular/core'`.

Side-note: `Type<>` is the same thing that `Injector.get()` takes as input.

Example Stackblitz application:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zy69nc?file=src/child.model.ts